# How to escape colon with following space in a GItLab CI/CD YAML value?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have the following line in GitLab CI/CD:

```yaml
  script:
    - echo "Backend image: $BACKEND_IMAGE"
```

But YAML interpreters treat this as an object. Then I googled this issue and tried this:

```yaml
  script:
    - echo "Backend image:: $BACKEND_IMAGE"
```

But it still doesn't work and GitLab job fails with the following:

> jobs:deploy review:script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep

If I remove colons at all it works fine. How to make a string value with colon and following space in GitLab CI/CD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work if you surround your string with single quotes:

```
script:
    - 'echo "Backend image: $BACKEND_IMAGE"'
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through several options, I found this below simple solution
Use like this,

```
Image="Backend image:"
export RESULT="$(echo "$Image" $BACKEND_IMAGE)" 
echo "Result is " $RESULT
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try and put your string in a variable first, then echo that variable:

```yaml
- ECHO_STRING=$(echo "Backend image:: $BACKEND_IMAGE")
- echo $ECHO_STRING
```

If not, try:

```yaml
- ECHO_STRING=$(echo "Backend image:\ $BACKEND_IMAGE" | tr -d '\')
- echo $ECHO_STRING>>
```

(Replace `ECHO_STRING` by a more meaning variable name)